# re module Different behavior of \w when using \b

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to do a whole-word match right now, and the \b flag is matching on things that aren't word boundaries. My regular expression currently looks like this:

```
m = re.compile(r'\bT5\b')
```

This works well for most occurances of "T5", but the \b will match symbols such as $, or #, or !.  Because of that, strings like '#T5' or '!T5' will match the above regex. These symbols do not match the \w flag on my system.  What I would like to match is the 'T5' in ' T5 ' or 'T5 ' or ' T5'-- basically the string with whitespace around it, or with the empty string around it.  Am I doing something wrong here?  I haven't found any mention of a discrepancy between \b and \w.  How can I adapt my regex so that it won't match symbols such as those above?

Comment: Can you *give an actual example input* and expected output...

Comment: Sorry-- thought I was clear.  Updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\b` means the boundary between a word character (alphanumeric and `_`), and a non-word character. In this case you want to have a zero width negative look-behind and lookahead; using the "non-whitespace character" atom `\S`.

Try:

```
m = re.compile(r'(?<!\S)T5(?!\S)')
```

There `(?<!\S)` means "if not preceded by a non-whitespace character" and `(?!\S)` means `if not succeeded by a non-whitespace character.

Comment: How about `r'(?<=\s)T5(?=\s)'`?

Comment: Thanks guys!  Both of these regexes work perfectly.  I'm adding a regex book to my christmas list...

Comment: @RohitJain actually yours fails to match at the beginning out end of the string